# Intel tbb parallel_for: pass class member function with parameters?

Tags: c++, multithreading, tbb

Is it possible to pass a class member function (with parameters) to parallel_for? Something along the lines:

```
void classT::A(const tbb::blocked_range<std::size_t>& r,b) {}

void classT::B(e,f,g) { 
   tbb::parallel_for( blocked_range<size_t>(0,n), <need to call A with parameter b, 
                                                                       along with r> ) 
}
```

Comment: If you can use C++11 features, lambda-expression may help you.

Comment: Excellent; I was able to do this:

Comment: parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<size_t>(0,n), [=](const tbb::blocked_range<std::size_t>& r) {
   this->A(r, b);
  } );

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this example](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~gibson/tbbexample/main.C.html).

They create a class and suply the class with a all the parameters needed.
In that class is also a `operator()` which does an oppertion on the data.
The parallel_for is then called with a instance of that class.

```
parallel_for(blocked_range<int>(0, nElements, 100), ArraySummer( p_A, p_B, p_SUM_TBB ) ); 
//The class is arraysummer
```

How you could do it :

```
class ClassTACaller
{
   int* m_parameter;
   ClassT* m_Tinstance

public:

   ClassTACaller(ClassT* tinstance, int* param):m_parameter(param), m_Tinstance(tinstance){}
   void operator() ( const blocked_range<int>& r ) const 
   {
      m_Tinstance->A(r, param);
   }
};

parallel_for(blocked_range<int>(0, nElements, 100), ClassTACaller(&classTinstance, &x));
```

Comment: thanks. I did come across such examples in my search. But I was wondering if there is a way to package my tasks in the class's member functions itself (like the way people do with boost::thread, and boost::bind) instead of building separate classes for every task. Is this possible?

Comment: If your compiler supports c++11, you can use `std::bind`, it schould work. `std::bind` does the same thing as I did, but it uses templates.

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't seem to. I tried; here is what it looks like:   _parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<size_t>(0,n), std::bind( &classT::A, this, b, std::placeholders::_1 ));_ and there are several errors, the first of which is:

Comment: /usr/local/include/tbb/parallel_for.h:102:37: error: no matching function for call to object of type 'const std::__1::__bind<void (A::*)(tbb::concurrent_vector<int,
      tbb::cache_aligned_allocator<int> > &, const tbb::blocked_range<unsigned long> &), classT *, tbb::concurrent_vector<int, tbb::cache_aligned_allocator<int> > &,
      std::__1::placeholders::__ph<1> &>'
        void run_body( Range &r ) { my_body( r ); }

Comment: Just for clarification: the concurrent_vector<int> is the "b" parameter.